# How to roll a contest of will?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

In making a campaign, I foresee the following situation occurring:

A necromancer summons undead and thus controls them. A party member has an item allowing him to control undead. Seeing as low level undead are mindless, the control of them becomes a contest of will between the two mages.

Which bonuses, if any, should be applied to the rolls? Should they roll for control every round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic mechanic would be opposed rolls -- 1d20 + bonus, higher roll wins, ties go to current controller.  The most applicable stat to base the rolls on is probably Wisdom, being a sort of force-of-will kind of contest, but the necromancer might be using his intelligence to exert control, and/or the party member's item might be based on a different stat, maybe even Charisma.

I would give the necromancer his proficiency bonus for controlling undead, and might also so do for some types of clerics, if the player happens to be one of those.

They should roll for control every round that they both choose to contest the control, yes.  And that contested roll should be the action for the challenger, and a reaction for the challenged (also meaning that if he has spent his reaction on something else already, he would not be able to retain control).

I might also rule that, under the conditions of such a contest, it requires concentration to do so, and that thus a contestant might be able to be disrupted and lose the concentration and thus the contest.

You will have to decide what other spells or other modifiers can be applied to such rolls.  Probably no one can use a *help* action to give advantage (but might be possible using a telepathic link?).  *Bless* spell doesn't apply, since that's only attacks and saving throws, but *Guidance* spell might apply.  Bardic Inspiration might be applicable as well.  Luck?  Divination dice?  Inspiration points?  Jack-of-all-Trades?

Note, though, that zombies are pretty much the only mindless undead -- skeletons are not mindless, nor are ghouls, etc.  That may affect how you decide to run this.

Answer (score 7):

### More detail needed

> A necromancer summons undead and thus controls them.

**How?**

> A party member has an item allowing him to control undead.

**How?**

If the necromancer is using the *Animate Dead* or *Create Undead* spell then he can command the animated undead using a bonus action on his turn.

If the necromancer is using something like the Command Undead ability they get at 14th level then the *creature* makes a Charisma saving throw versus the necromancer's spell save DC. It then "obeys your commands" which do not appear to require *any* action to give.

If you want things to work this way then one person *has* control and the other  can take control by using an action to force the *undead* to save against their wizard spell save DC. For a wizard, this is 8 + Int bonus + proficiency; for a non-wizard this is 8 + proficiency bonus.

Controlling undead is more a "You, go do that" fire and forget bonus action rather than a continuous mental exercise.